# Identifying objects in Tosca with Xpath

Tags: xpath, tosca

I am recently brushing up my skills in TOSCA, I was working on it 2 years ago and switched to Selenium, I noticed that the new TOSCA allows identification using Xpath, and I am really familiar with it now, however, I cannot make it work in TOSCA and I am sure the object identification works because I am testing my xpath in google chrome developer tools.

Something as simple as (//*[text()='Forgot Password?'])[1] does not seem to be working.  Could I be missing something?

This is the webpage I am using as reference for this example:
https://www.freecrm.com/index.html

Answer (score 2):

XPath certainly can be used to identify elements of an HTML web UI in Tosca.

Since the question was originally posted, the "Forgot Password?" link at https://www.freecrm.com/index.html appears to have changed so that it's text is now "Forgot your password?" and is actually located at https://ui.freecrm.com/.
To account for that change, this answer uses "(//*[text()='Forgot your password?'])[1]" instead of the expression provided in the original post.

With the text modification, the expression works to idenfity the element in XScan after wrapping it in double quotes:

```
"(//*[text()='Forgot your password?'])[1]"
```

Some things to keep in mind when using XPath in Tosca:

1. It seems that XPath expressions need to be wrapped in double quotes (") so that XScan knows when to start evaluating XPath instead of using its normal rules.  Looking closely at the expression that is pregenerated when XScan starts, we see that it is wrapped in double quotes:

```xml
"id('ui')/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]"
```

2. A valid XPath expression doesn't necessarily guarantee uniqueness, so it is helpful to pay attention to any feedback messages at the bottom of XScan.  There is a significant difference between "The selected element was not found" and "The selected element is not unique".  The former simply indicates XScan can't find a match, the latter indicates that XScan matches successfully, but cannot uniquely identify the element.
3. My experience has been that it helps to explicitly identify the element to reduce the possibility of ambiguity.  If the idea is to target the anchor element in order for tests to click a link, then reducing scope from *any* element i.e. "(//*[text()='Forgot your Password?'])[1]" to only match *anchor* elements with that text "//a[text()='Forgot your password?']".
4. In general, Tricentis (or at least the trainers with whom I have spoken) recommends using methods other than XPath to identify a target if they are available.  That said, in my experience I've had better luck with XPath than with "Identify by Anchor".

   - An XPath expression is visible and editable in the XModuleAttribute properties without having to rescan.  Personally, I find it easier to work with than the XML value of the RelativeId property that is generated when using Identify by Anchor.
   - With Anchor, I've had issues where XModuleAttributes scanned in one browser can no longer be found when switching to another browser, specifically from IE to Chrome.  With XPath, I've not had these issues.
5. While XPath works well to identify the properties of one element with attributes of another because it can identify the relationship between them (very common with controls in Angular applications), the same can often be accomplished by adapting the engine layer using the [TBox API](https://documentation.tricentis.com/devcorner/1320/tboxapi/index.html#topic1.html) (i.e. building a custom control).  This requires some initial work up front from developer resources, but it can significantly improve how tests steer these controls in addition to reducing the need for Automation Specialists to have to rely on XPath.

Answer (score -1):

What I know is that you can identify elements with XPath when working with XML messages in Tosca API testing. Your use case seems to be UI testing, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: It's also possible to use XPath for UI testing.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use XScan to scan the page? Usually Tosca automatically calculates an XPath expression for you that you can use immediately.

Please see the [manual for details](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.0.0&url=engines_3.0/xbrowser/xbrowser_controls.htm).

If it still does not work please try to be more specific? What isn't working? Error message? Unexpected behavior? ...

Answer (score -1):

Tosca provides its set of attributes for locating any type of elements. You can directly select any number of attributes you want to make your element unique along with index of that element. Just make sure that you are not using any dynamic values in 'id' or 'class-name' of that element, also the index range is not so large like 20 out of 100; it could be 5 out of 10, which will be helpful if you need to update it in future.
Also take help of parent elements which will be uniquely located easily and then locate your expected element.

Answer (score -1):

TOSCA provide various ways to locate an element just like selenium plus in addition it will provide other properties also.Under transition properties you will find x path and it will be absolute x path since you know selenium you know the difference between absolute and relative x path. I would suggest you to go with.
1.Identify by **ID OR name**
2. Identify by **anchor**
if your relative x path is not working

Answer (score -2):

Try load all properties on the right side bottom. But it showed for me without clicking on it. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWXs5.png)